# How to get rid off of duplicate results from JOIN after using aggregation functions with different GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to use aggregation functions on a table to track the time progression of tasks assigned to users.

Part of the table looks something like this:

Table `tasks`:

```
TaskID | UserID | RegistrationDate | StartDate  |   EndDate  | Status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 tId1  |  uId1  |     dd/10/2000   | dd/10/2000 | dd/10/2000 | completed    
 tId2  |  uId2  |     dd/10/2000   | dd/10/2000 | dd/12/2000 | completed
 tId3  |  uId3  |     dd/10/2000   | dd/12/2000 | dd/02/2001 | completed  
 tId4  |  uId4  |     dd/10/2000   | dd/11/2000 | dd/11/2000 | cancelled
 tId5  |  uId5  |     dd/11/2000   | dd/11/2000 | dd/01/2001 | completed
 tId6  |  uId6  |     dd/12/2000   |    NULL    |    NULL    | registered
 tId7  |  uId7  |     dd/12/2000   | dd/12/2000 |    NULL    | in progress    
 tId8  |  uId8  |     dd/01/2001   | dd/01/2001 | dd/01/2001 | cancelled    
 tId9  |  uId9  |     dd/01/2001   | dd/01/2001 | dd/02/2001 | completed    
 tId10 |  uId10 |     dd/02/2001   |    NULL    |    NULL    | registered
 tId11 |  uId11 |     dd/02/2001   | dd/02/2001 | dd/02/2001 | completed
 tId12 |  uId12 |     dd/02/2001   | dd/02/2001 | dd/02/2001 | completed
......
```

My goal is to be able to use aggregators according to different criteria so I can get something along these lines:

```
  Year | Month | NewR | Completed_A| Completed_B | Cancelled_A | Cancelled_B | OpenR | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2000  |   10  |   4  |      3     |      1      |      1      |      0      |   0   |
 2000  |   11  |   1  |      1     |      0      |      0      |      1      |   0   |
 2000  |   12  |   2  |      0     |      1      |      0      |      0      |   2   |
 2001  |   1   |   2  |      1     |      1      |      1      |      1      |   0   |
 2001  |   2   |   3  |      1     |      4      |      0      |      0      |   3   |
......
```

`RegistrationDate`, `StartDate` and `EndDate` are all timestamps, and I am trying to sort my results on a chronological monthly basis.  What I am having problem with is that I am doing this with a `GROUP BY` statement, and while I do want the time progression to be based on the registration date, I dont necessarily want to group my outputs by it. For instance, in the table above `NewR` are all registrations that occur on the month corresponding to `RegistrationDate`, `Completed_A` counts tasks that were registered at `RegistrationDate` and completed anywhen, while `Completed_B` counts tasks that were registered anywhen but completed on `EndDate`, thus to get criteria `A` I need to `GROUP BY RegistrationDate`, and to get criteria `B` I need to `GROUP BY EndDate`.

I need to be able to do this in a single query, the way Im currently doing it is in a messy nested `SELECT` with a `JOIN`, but I am getting redundant columns that I would like to get rid off and have not been able to figure out how. My code looks something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 (SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(RegistrationDate, 'yyyy-mm')                    AS MonthYear    
,   DATE_PART('year',RegistrationDate)                      AS rYear
,   DATE_PART('month',RegistrationDate)                     AS rMonth
,   COUNT(*)                                                AS NewR
, SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS Completed_A
, SUM(CASE WHEN Status IN ('Registered','In Progress')
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                                     AS OpenR
FROM Tasks 
GROUP BY MonthYear, rYear, rMonth)      AS  T1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(EndDate, 'yyyy-mm')                             AS MonthYear    
,   DATE_PART('year', EndDate)                              AS EndYear
,   DATE_PART('month', EndDate)                             AS EndMonth
, SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS Completed_B
FROM Tasks
GROUP BY MonthYear, EndYear, EndMonth)  AS  T2

ON T1.MonthYear = T2.MonthYear
ORDER BY MonthYear
```

I added a column that has both the month and year because that's the only way I could figure out how to simplify the correct sorting on the final joined output, and I am also getting some cumulative sums so it really helps me to just `SUM (stuff) OVER (ORDER BY MonthYear)`

1. Is there better way overall to use aggregation on a single statement with different `GROUP BY`s?
2. How can I get rid off the duplicate month, year and `'yyyy-mm'` columns? I dont really want to not use the `SELECT *` at the top because on my actual table I have a lot more columns that I cannot afford to select one by one, and I am also doing this for a few other criteria that are also time-related (so in reality my table has as many duplicate redundant month and year columns as however many criterias I am using). I have tried adding a `DISTINCT` but that didnt help.

Oh and Im currently using PostgreSQL but theres a chance that this will be migrated to SQL Server. (I am however trying to use as much standard SQL as possible and avoiding particular SQL Server functionalities).

I did notice there were similar questions but the answers did not really help me for this one.

Comment: If you have redundant columns, just change `SELECT *` to `SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln` where `col1... coln` are the columns you actually want.

Comment: This is something I was attempting to avoid doing, but it seems like there is no way around it. Answer below was helpful even though it also does not use the `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the result, you need to use `subquery` and you can't use `SELECT *`.

The following query using `UNION SELECT` may be similar to what you said.

```
SELECT
  Year
, Month
, SUM(CASE WHEN DTYPE='R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                AS NewR
, SUM(CASE WHEN DTYPE='R' AND Status = 'Completed'
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                                     AS Completed_A
, SUM(CASE WHEN DTYPE='E' AND Status = 'Completed'
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                                     AS Completed_B
, SUM(CASE WHEN DTYPE='R' AND Status IN ('Registered','In Progress')
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                                     AS OpenR
FROM
 (SELECT
      'R' AS DTYPE
  ,   DATE_PART('year',RegistrationDate)                      AS Year
  ,   DATE_PART('month',RegistrationDate)                     AS Month
  ,   Status
  FROM Tasks
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      'E' AS DTYPE
  ,   DATE_PART('year',EndDate)
  ,   DATE_PART('month',EndDate)
  ,   Status
  FROM Tasks) T
WHERE Year IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Year, Month
ORDER BY Year, Month;
```

Comment: It would have never occurred to me to use a variable in the `CASE` statements, this actually works great! It makes it much easier for me to keep adding more criterias to evaluate and frees me from having to worry about grouping shenaningans. I unfortunately cannot yet vote on answers but I really appreciate this, thanks!